# How to use AdaptiveCards with a LUIS based Azure WebApp Bot (Microsoft BotFramework) C#

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, adaptive-cards

I have a WebApp Bot enabled in the Skype for Business channel, the purpose of the bot is to do a SQL Query and return some data i.e. Query: "Who is Joe Bloggs", Response: "Name: Joe Bloggs, Mob: 07123456789, JobTitle: Associate" etc..

I want to have this information returned as an adaptive card rather than just text, so was looking at how to do this. The tutorials show how to implement this using C# on a generic chatbot, but is not specific enough on where in a LUIS bot I would add this code (as LUIS is passing the message around for Intent Recognition, so is more complicated than simply 'if activity type is Message, attach AdaptiveCard').

Would it be the MessageController.cs? or the BasicLUISDialog.cs perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, while SfB currently supports Hero Cards, it does not support Adaptive cards at this time. You can check which channel supports which format at this link:

[Channel Inspector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/SkypeForBusiness?f=AdaptiveCards&e=example1)

That being said, cards are created in the dialog, not the controller. You'd make them in the BasicLUISDialog.cs.

Answer (score 0):

SFB provides a very limited functionality wrt user styling. Buttons and javascript is not supported. You can color and change size of text your text using some html.